# Reading numbers from input Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to have a function that reads arbitrary int's until the number '0' is inserted, and then presents the numbers inserted in an ordered list.

For that i wrote this function:

```
import Data.List

readIntegers :: IO()
readIntegers = do
    putStrLn "insert a number: "
    num<-getLine
    let list = ordList ((read num :: Int):list)
    if (read num == 0)  
    then print list 
    else readIntegers
  where ordList ::[Int]->[Int]
        ordList [] = []
        ordList xs = sort xs
```

This compiles just fine, but when i insert the number '0', it gives me this error:

```
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more sophisticated solution, note that this is an *unfold* and you can use `unfoldM` from Control.Monad.Loops to implement it:

```
import Control.Monad.Loops (unfoldM)

readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = unfoldM $ fmap (check . read) getLine
  where check x = if x == 0 then Nothing else Just x
```

This has the nice property that it returns the list in the order in which it was read.

Answer (score 7):

As @phg points out, you are essentially constructing an infinite list, and actually evaluating it causes the loop error. A simple implementation to resolve this issue is to define a helper function which takes an additional parameter - a list to store all the inputs read in from the screen, like so:

```
readInteger :: IO ()
readInteger = readInteger' []
    where
        readInteger' x = do
        putStrLn "insert a number: "
        num<-getLine        
        if ((read num :: Int) == 0)  
        then print $ ordList x 
        else readInteger' $ (read num :: Int):x
        where ordList ::[Int]->[Int]
              ordList [] = []
              ordList xs = sort xs
```

Please note that the above is essentially just an implementation of @phg's answer, but with some changes to your original logic. Firstly, since 0 is a sentinel value, we shouldn't be appending that to our list. Second, we do not need to sort the list every single time we are adding a value to it. Sorting once at the time of printing/passing to another function is sufficient.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QWP1689)

If you want to read an unspecified number of integers without prompting for user input and cut it off the moment you encounter 0, you would probably do well to use `getContents`, which will read everything from the standard input as a single string, lazily.

Then, it is a simple matter of parsing it to a list of numbers and doing what you want with it, like so:

```
readIntegers :: ()
readIntegers = do
   a <- getContents
   let b = ordList $ takeWhile (/= 0) $ map (\x -> read x :: Int) $ words a          
   mapM (putStrLn . show) b
 where ordList ::[Int]->[Int]
       ordList [] = []
       ordList xs = sort xs
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let list = ordList ((read num :: Int):list)
```

This is basically a recursive definition of a list of the form `[x, x, ...]` (like if you wrote an equation saying `x = 1 + x`). That is perfectly fine by itself, since Haskell is lazy; however, if you try to `print list` (aka "solve the equation"), it will fail, since it will try to print infinitely many numbers.

You probably have a misconception about the workings of the `(:)` operator. Haskell functions will never perform an assignment operation and concatenate `num` onto `list` by changing it, like in imperative languages. There are only *pure* functions.

If you want to accumulate all numbers, you should try to come up with a recursive definition of `readIntegers`, keeping its state (the `list`) in an additional parameter (there are also more sophisticated ways, hiding the state passing, but more complicated to use for a beginner).

Comment: Actually, `list` by itself is already diverging since `ordList` is strict on the spine.