# Haskell - keep adding user input ints until a negative is encountered

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a program in Haskell that takes in user inputs, adds each input line up, and spits out the final sum once the user inputs a negative number (the total sum not including the negative number, to be specific). I attempt

```
    sumF1 :: IO ()
    sumF1 = do
        totSum <- sumF2 0
        print totSum

    sumF2 :: Int -> IO Int
    sumF2 prev = do 
        n<-getInt
        if n<0
            then return prev
            else sumF2 (prev+n)
```

However, when I try this, I just get a function that prints on every single line and always repeats the input as opposed to summing it up. How do I fix it so that it only prints a sum at the end and that it adds properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading numbers from input Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011292/reading-numbers-from-input-haskell)

Comment: That code does what you describe (assuming `getInt :: IO Int; getInt = fmap read getLine` or equivalent). Either you're not showing us all your code or you're trying to do something else.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to create a program in Haskell that takes in user inputs,
>   adds each input line up, and spits out the final sum once the user
>   inputs a negative number

If this is the only thing you want, then you can simply write

```
main = getContents >>= print . sum . takeWhile (>= 0) . map read . lines
```

Otherwise you can use this combinator

```
repeatWhile :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]
repeatWhile p a = do
    x <- a
    if p x
        then (x:) <$> repeatWhile p a
        else return []
```

like this

```
main = repeatWhile (>= 0) readLn >>= print . sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a function which gets the next number and returns a "IO (Maybe Integer)" with "Just" for a positive input and "Nothing" for a negative one. Then use that in a recursive function to create a list of integers (hint: one of its arguments will be the list of integers so far). Then use that in a function that adds up all the integers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is broken, but I don't know your definition of getInt. For me this one works fine:

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = do str <- getLine
        return (read str)
```

taken from [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/01/introduction-to-haskell-io.html).

Comment: Your source says that `getLine` is provided by the prelude, not `getInt`. There is no `getInt` in the prelude.

Comment: You can write that much more concisely: `getInt = getLine >>= read`. Obviously it still needs the type signature.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions for the functions `sumF1` and `sumF2` seem to work well, probably the issue is with the `getInt` function you use to get `n` each time.

Try adding this line for the definition of `getInt`:

```
getInt = getLine >>= \n -> return (read n :: Int)
```

Which uses `getLine` from the prelude.

Comment: That's the implementation I'm also using. My code still has problems where it takes in each line as input and prints each line back out to me (kinda like echoing) instead of actually functioning properly